# How to exit out of ForEach loop once condition is met

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a small script that will generate an email if an employee has attendance issues. I'm using two templates, one if an employee has a "late" infraction and one if there are other infractions not including "lates" (for example, no-call no-show, unexcused call-offs, etc). However, in my forEach loop, I cannot figure out how to exit the loops so I don't get multiple emails. How can I exit the loop once one (1) email has been sent?

```
function sendEiEmail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Attendance Narrative Generator');
  var arr = ss.getRange(7, 1, 10, 1).getValues(); //Get all values from sheet
  // Logger.log(arr);
var htmlBodyNoLate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AttendanceNoLate").evaluate().getContent();
var htmlBodyLate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AttendanceLate").evaluate().getContent();

  arr.forEach(function(res) {
    if(res == 'Late'){

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: `Attendance Infractions Narrative - ${firstName} ${lastName} #${employeeEID}`,
    htmlBody: htmlBodyLate,
  });
 return;

  }else{

 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: `Attendance Infractions Narrative - ${firstName} ${lastName} #${employeeEID}`,
    htmlBody: htmlBodyNoLate,
  });

}

  });
}
```

Comment: You can replace `arr.forEach(res => {...})` to `for (var res of arr) {...}` and to break the 'for loop' at any iteration you want.

Comment: You cannot break out of a forEach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to break forEach loop.
(unless you want to use exceptions, but it's not recommended)
There are two options to solve the problem:

1. Change the loop type to for, and not forEach, and then use the break statement.
2. Use a flag to know that the email was sent:

```
function sendEiEmail() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Attendance Narrative Generator');
    var arr = ss.getRange(7, 1, 10, 1).getValues(); //Get all values from sheet
    var htmlBodyNoLate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AttendanceNoLate").evaluate().getContent();
    var htmlBodyLate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AttendanceLate").evaluate().getContent();

    var isEmailSent = false;
    arr.forEach(function (res) {
        if (isEmailSent == false) {
            if (res == 'Late') {
                MailApp.sendEmail({
                    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    subject: `Attendance Infractions Narrative - ${firstName} ${lastName} #${employeeEID}`,
                    htmlBody: htmlBodyLate,
                });
                isEmailSent = true;
            } else {
                MailApp.sendEmail({
                    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    subject: `Attendance Infractions Narrative - ${firstName} ${lastName} #${employeeEID}`,
                    htmlBody: htmlBodyNoLate,
                });
                isEmailSent = true;
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Ok good to know, for the sake of my understanding I'll have to figure out how to change the loop type into a For loop, but for now, this work-around works. Really appreciate it